# AVAudioPlayer decreasing level slowly

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have created a sound, which I play like this :

```
NSURL *musicFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"My music"
                                           withExtension:@"mp3"];
self.backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile
                                                              error:nil];
self.backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops = -1;
[self.backgroundMusic play];
```

But when I change of view, I want to stop the music. But slowly, smoothly, not immediately. As when you put your application in background, your music doesn't stop immediately but in approximatively 0.5s.

Is it possible ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and there are several ways of achieving this "fade out" effect.

I did it like this in an earlier project and it worked really well for me

```
-(void)fadeOut {  

    if (self.backgroundMusic.volume > 0.05) {

        self.backgroundMusic.volume = self.backgroundMusic.volume - 0.05;

        // Volume will be zero after ~0.5 seconds
        [self performSelector:@selector(fadeOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0/40.0];   

     } else {
        [self.backgroundMusic stop];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer and decrease the volume of AVAudioPlayer.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                      target: self
                      selector:@selector(timerTriggered:)
                      userInfo: nil repeats:YES];

-(void)timerTriggered:(NSTimer *)timer
{
  [appSoundPlayer setVolume: appSoundPlayer.volume - 0.1];

  if(appSoundPlayer.volume == 0.0)
  { 
    [timer inValidate];

    timer = nil;
  }
}
```